# Sort by column selecting the minimum date of that group

Tags: postgresql, group-by, having

**Table:**

```
worker_id | created_at | state_id
29447     | 14-6-2021, 15:29 | 12
29447     | 12-6-2021, 14:11 | 12
29447     | 11-6-2021, 10:47 | 9
29447     | 10-6-2021, 10:21 | 9
29447     | 14-6-2021, 15:29 | 12
29447     | 12-4-2021, 7:03  | 11
29447     | 10-4-2021, 11:39 | 11
29447     | 10-4-2021, 10:19 | 11
```

**What I want**

```
worker_id | created_at | state_id
29447     | 12-6-2021, 14:11 | 12
29447     | 10-6-2021, 10:21 | 9
29447     | 9-6-2021, 11:27  | 12
29447     | 10-4-2021, 10:19 | 11
```

**I tried with:**

```
SELECT worker_id,created_at,state_id 
FROM (select min(created_at) AS created_at,worker_id,state_id from workermonitoring
where worker_id = 29447
group by worker_id,state_id) as A
ORDER  BY A.worker_id, created_at DESC
```

**And result:**

```
worker_id | created_at | state_id
29447     | 9-6-2021, 11:27  | 12
29447     | 10-6-2021, 10:21 | 9
29447     | 10-4-2021, 10:19 | 11
```

I need to group it by state_id and from that group obtain the minimum date, but it must also be considered that a state_id can be on another date and that would be considered another group

Comment: 9 and 11 also fall on more than one date.  Why do they only show up once in your desired output?

Comment: And none of the 12's occur on either the date, or the time, of `9-6-2021, 11:27`

Answer (score 1):

1. Key is to get the DATE part only by truncating the time part  along with the other columns because we will need to group by the date part to get the earliest timestamp.

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT worker_id,
                created_at,
                Date(created_at) trunc_date,
                state_id
         FROM   worker)
```

2. after getting the above dataset in a CTE , list the rows in ascending order of created_at with timestamp and pick the first row(which will be the earliest timestamp)

Full SQL:

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT worker_id,
                created_at,
                Date(created_at) trunc_date,
                state_id
         FROM   worker)
SELECT worker_id,
       created_at,
       state_id
FROM   (SELECT worker_id,
               created_at,
               state_id,
               Row_number()
                 OVER (
                   partition BY trunc_date
                   ORDER BY created_at) lst
        FROM   cte) inline_view
WHERE  lst = 1
```

Output:

```
 worker_id |     created_at      | state_id
-----------+---------------------+----------
     29447 | 2021-04-10 10:19:00 |       11
     29447 | 2021-04-12 07:03:00 |       11
     29447 | 2021-06-10 10:21:00 |        9
     29447 | 2021-06-11 10:47:00 |        9
     29447 | 2021-06-12 14:11:00 |       12
     29447 | 2021-06-14 15:29:00 |       12
(6 rows)
```

Sample data in **worker** table:

```
postgres=# select * from worker;
 worker_id |     created_at      | state_id
-----------+---------------------+----------
     29447 | 2021-06-14 15:29:00 |       12
     29447 | 2021-06-12 14:11:00 |       12
     29447 | 2021-06-10 10:21:00 |        9
     29447 | 2021-06-14 15:29:00 |       12
     29447 | 2021-04-12 07:03:00 |       11
     29447 | 2021-04-10 11:39:00 |       11
     29447 | 2021-04-10 10:19:00 |       11
     29447 | 2021-06-11 10:47:00 |        9
(8 rows)
```